# int android.widget.ListAdapter.getCount() issue in StaggeredGridView

Tags: android, staggered-gridview

I am using `StaggeredGridView` to display `GridView` item based on item height. It is working fine in many versions. But, recently I found that it is showing error in android 5.1. I am sharing `Logcat` as below. Please check it out help me to solve this issue.

```
06-03 15:17:22.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29840): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.widget.ListAdapter.getCount()' on a null object reference
06-03 16:03:25.229: E/AndroidRuntime(25195):    at com.etsy.android.grid.ExtendableListView.getLastVisiblePosition(ExtendableListView.java:1824)
06-03 16:03:25.229: E/AndroidRuntime(25195):    at android.widget.AdapterView.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AdapterView.java:978)
06-03 16:03:25.229: E/AndroidRuntime(25195):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AbsListView.java:1490)
06-03 16:03:25.229: E/AndroidRuntime(25195):    at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:5317)
06-03 16:03:25.229: E/AndroidRuntime(25195):    at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:5304)
06-03 16:03:25.229: E/AndroidRuntime(25195):    at android.view.View$SendViewStateChangedAccessibilityEvent.run(View.java:21039)
06-03 16:03:25.229: E/AndroidRuntime(25195):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
06-03 16:03:25.229: E/AndroidRuntime(25195):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-03 16:03:25.229: E/AndroidRuntime(25195):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-03 16:03:25.229: E/AndroidRuntime(25195):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
06-03 16:03:25.229: E/AndroidRuntime(25195):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-03 16:03:25.229: E/AndroidRuntime(25195):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-03 16:03:25.229: E/AndroidRuntime(25195):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
06-03 16:03:25.229: E/AndroidRuntime(25195):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

I could also see warning message as below :

```
06-03 15:52:05.804: W/art(21986): Before Android 4.1, method void com.etsy.android.grid.ExtendableListView.reportScrollStateChange(int) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.AbsListView
```

**My code :**
Mainactivity.java

```
productGridviewAdapter = new ProductGridviewAdapter(getActivity(), productList,);
gvProducts.setAdapter(productGridviewAdapter);
```

ProductGridviewAdapter.java

```
public ProductGridviewAdapter(Activity a,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arlData) {

        activity = a;
        data = arlData;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        WEBSITE_URL = activity.getResources().getString(R.string.website_url);

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgPhoto;
        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvType;
        TextView tvDiscountedPrice;
    }

    public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        products = new HashMap<String, String>();
        products = data.get(position);

        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            if (products.get("MRP").equals("0")) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.package_product_item, parent,
                        false);

                viewHolder.tvType = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvType);
            } else {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_item, parent, false);

                viewHolder.tvDiscountedPrice = (TextView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvDiscountedPrice);
                viewHolder.tvMRP = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvMRP);
                viewHolder.tvDiscount = (TextView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvDiscount);
            }

            viewHolder.imgPhoto = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgPhoto);
            viewHolder.tvName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            viewHolder.tvOutofStock = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvOutofStock);

            vi.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(WEBSITE_URL + products.get("Photo"),
                viewHolder.imgPhoto);
        viewHolder.tvName.setText(products.get("ProductName"));

        viewHolder.tvDiscountedPrice.setText(activity.getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.rs)
                    + " "
                    + products.get("DiscountedPrice"));


        return vi;
    }
```

Comment: please post your activity with adapter code

Comment: @ManishJain, sure. give me 15-20 minutes.

Comment: @ManishJain, Please check updated post.

Comment: check productList is null or not

Comment: yes, check that productList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> (), has been done or not in MainActivity

Comment: From logcat, IMO you should check the file `ExtendableListView.java` (com.etsy.android.grid.ExtendableListView), looks like that you use from `https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid` which has been deprecated as in their Readme?

Comment: But why I am not getting issue on all versions. I tested it on version 5.1 and that time only I am getting error.

Comment: @BNK, then what should i use ?

Comment: Not sure, perhaps at line #1824 (getLastVisiblePosition)

Comment: @BNK, interesting thing is that it is not giving error all the time, sometimes it works fine and sometimes it gives error in android version 5.1. no issue in any other device.

Comment: For now, to avoid that exception, I think you can check `if (... != null){...}`

Comment: @BNK, is there any better `StaggeredGridView` available as compared to etsy ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know :)

Comment: @JeetenParmar: suggest you prefer using Google's own RecyclerView with their StaggeredGridLayoutManager. We are doing the same internally at Etsy. (This is mentioned in the ReadMe doc of AndroidStaggeredGrid)

Check this [link](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your entire code but I can say under some conditions your ProductGridviewAdapter object has a null list. You want to look at your code and find when/where that might happen. Keep an eye for race conditions too where the object is constructed before the list is initialized. That can result in randomness which you are observing. I don't like leaving unknown conditions in the code, but if for any reason your list is null, you might want to treat it as empty. Additionally, you might want to initialize it to an empty list to start with. The following changes should get rid of the error, but not necessarily the underlying cause of the list being null. I strongly recommend you try to figure out why that happens, as it might be an indication of another (sometimes more serious) problem.

```
public ProductGridviewAdapter(Activity a,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arlData) {

        activity = a;
        //check for null here as a safety net
        if (arlData != null)
            data = arlData;
        else
            data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ...
    //if somehow data is set to null at some point, treat it as empty list
    public int getCount() {
        return data==null?0:data.size();
        //alternatively you might want to initialize data in this case
    }
```

Good luck!